# ワンライナーで変数を後ろから代入したい

Tags: linux, bash, shellscript

お世話になっております。

`ldapsearch` を頻繁に使うことがあり、コマンドが長いので変数を使っています。

```
i=aaaaa; ldapsearch -x -h 111.111.11.11 -p 11 ... myid=${i} objectclass=* >  `date +%Y%m%d`_${i}.txt
```

サーバ上で、シェルスクリプトを置いておけないのでできればワンライナーでやりたいと考えています。

現在のやり方だと、最初の i=を書き換えているのですが、前よりも最後に変数を貼るほうが楽そうなので後ろから代入する、あるいはそれに替わる方法はないでしょうか。（bashの動作として後ろからの代入がタブーなのは承知しております。無理を言ってすみません。）

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 検討してみます。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sh -c 'ldapsearch -x -h 111.111.11.11 -p 11 ... myid=${1} objectclass=* >`date +%Y%m%d`_${1}.txt' - aaaa
```

とか、

```
f() { ldapsearch -x -h 111.111.11.11 -p 11 ... myid=${1} objectclass=* >`date +%Y%m%d`_${1}.txt; }; f aaaa
```

OpenLDAP `ldapsearch`(1) のコマンドラインとしては不正っぽい気がしますが、それは適宜直してください。

Comment: 上手くいきました。さすがです！ありがとうございます